# Why did I loose access to the mailboxes on my old web/mail host after changing to a new one but keeping old MX values

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record

So I changed the NS records with registrar to point at the new webhosts DNS servers and edited the SOA record there, deleting the new hosts default MX records and instead putting in the old ones for the old web\mail hosts. The website A record is however pointing at the new webhosts servers and the site comes up fine.

But none of this should cause me to loose access to mailboxes on my old hosts mail server right? I log into the control panel on the old host, all the mailboxes are there, all the passwords are fine but I can't log in using either webmail or pop3, says incorrect log-in/password. I even created a new mailbox and password for it respectively, but it would not let me log in.

For what its worth I did not change\delete the records for 'A' on the old webhost zone file, since I am not hosting the site with them anymore and NS records are pointing to other hosts DNS servers/zone file so that shouldn't matter right?

The old hosts mailserver is also not simply down, I can tell because through the control panel I setup a mail forward for one of the existing inboxes and when sending mail to it, it receives it and forwards it fine. So from this I can deduce that I have correctly inputted the old hosts MX records into the zone file hosted on the new hosts DNS and the mail is being sent to the old hosts mail server(s) and is successfully forwarded by it. But why can't I log into those account/inboxes anymore ?

Comment: What platform is mail being hosted from on old/new?  Are you trying to just change DNS providers, but still point to your old mail servers?  Verify the DNS of the webmail/pop3 address you are using resolves to the IP address it should.  The fact that you are getting a login prompt at all indicates you are reaching something, you just need to make sure its the correct system/IP etc.

Comment: How are you trying to connect to the server, by name or ip address? If by name, does it resolve to the old or the new server?

Comment: @floyd Of course  I am getting a log-in prompt at the old host, it's a major shared hosting provider why shouldn't I? I log into their control panel and all my mailboxes are there but I can't log into them through their webmail access portal or via POP3. All I did was point NS records at the registrar side to the new hosts DNS servers and edited the SOA\zone files hosted by the new hosts DNS servers to use my old hosts MX records. POP3 is pop3.oldhost.com, not associated with my account. Maybe the old hosts configuration for my account has gone wacko and MX\A records not the culprit.

Comment: So you switched NS and SOA to your new host.  Did you transfer dns zones to your new hosts DNS servers? To me it sounds like a DNS resolution problem, and I would verify A, MX, CNAME records are all resolving properly from some external DNS tool.

Comment: @floyd Doing a DNS lookup seems to return proper values for the MX records and it's pointing to my old hosts mail servers mx1.spaceweb.ru etc. Network-Tools.com still shows old records though with A record also still pointing at the old host. http://www.iptools.com/dnstools.php?tool=dns&user_data=www.ecww.ru&type=MX

Comment: It doesn't matter where the MX points to. It matters where you connect to retrieve your email. Now that may be the same server as the MX, but it's irrelevant. What name do you connect to when retrieveing your email and what does that name resolve to?

Comment: @joeqwerty You mean the actual pop3? pop3.spaceweb.ru and webmail: webmail.sweb.ru ? Or is there some connection string with mailbox username+password I should be able to derive from somewhere and analyze ?

Comment: Yes, I'm asking where you connect to retrieve your email for the old host. Where does your email client connect? Is it pop3.oldhost.com? If so, have you verified that pop3.oldhost.com resolves to the correct ip address?

Comment: @joeqwerty Well yeah it resolves to one of spaceweb.ru POP servers.Are you suggesting that my mailbox accounts are not on the said server? As that's the only pop3 address they provide.

Comment: No, I'm not suggesting that. I was just trying to esablish that the email server you're trying to connect to is in fact the correct server.

Comment: @joeqwerty But it seems like an entirely restricted problem to my mailbox accounts on the spaceweb.ru servers and not a DNS issue would you say? Else I see no other reason why I can't log-into their webmail using the same email account credentials that worked yesterday and said mailboxes exist on their servers. Or could there be some kind of domain tracing\validation that goes on in the background ?

Comment: @floyd What do you mean by DNS zone transfer, when I created a new account on the new host it asked me for a domain name and created respective domain.com Zone entry in their DNS system and respective SOA record, which by default had the MX records pointing at their mail (i.e @ 20 MX.SM-22-1GB.RU) servers which I then changed to the ones for my old host (@ 10 MX1.SPACEWEB.RU). Considering I pointed the NS records to the new hosts DNS servers, the zone file existing on the old hosts DNS server should be irrelevant now ?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently because the 'A' record for the domain was changed to point at the new host for some reason this caused issues when trying to log in through web-mail or pop3 to access the mailboxes on the old host even though the MX records were still pointing at the old hosts mailservers, in order for the mailboxes to start working and authenticating me, the tech support at the old host side had to make some changes to my account configuration.